# Http Network Monitor to catch all http requests to a page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My requirement is to catch all the requests coming into my MVC website. It should behave like Fiddler. So lets suppose I am loading 4 JS files and 4 Image files, then the total number of requests which I need to catch is 9(1 for view/action, 4 JS, 4 image).

Comment: *My requirement is to catch all the requests coming into my MVC website* restricted to the app only? perhaps you can try [`HttpModule`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms178468(v=vs.85).aspx).. look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11508232/4648586) for some comparison about it against ActionFilter.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch and count it in Global.asax.cs

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
        SystemReporter.NewRequest();
    }

    public static class SystemReporter
    {   
          static int requestCounter;

          public static void NewRequest()
          {
                requestCounter++;
                //save it to database 
                //And other logic for manipulation
          }
     }
```

Comment: With this I am able to capture the request hits but how will I also capture the JS file as well as Image file requests which are also GetRequest from the page